# Unable to update TextView from location update

Tags: java, android, textview, geolocation

I'm just fetching the current location of the device and displaying on a TextView but the TextView does not show the results, however , it seems that the java code is fetching the location correctly but not updating the TextView as I have tried a lot relevant codes without error of location fetching.
Moreover, I am using a physical device to run the Application, not the emulator.
The recent code I've tried is as below:

```
public class roadSideSelection extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, LocationListener {

    int MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION=100;
    int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION=100;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected Context context;
    TextView txtLat;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_road_side_selection);

        marshmallowGPSPremissionCheck();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        txtLat = findViewById(R.id.latitudeTextview);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        txtLat = findViewById(R.id.latitudeTextview);
        String s = getString(R.string.latitude, location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        txtLat.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }

    private void marshmallowGPSPremissionCheck() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                && checkSelfPermission(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        } else {
            //   gps functions.
               Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @Nullable String[] permissions,@Nullable int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
'''

Strings.xml
```

Latitude: %1$d; Longitude: %2$d

Comment: any error in logs ?

Comment: also share your String declaration in string.xml

Comment: @Jacks No errors in logcat
strings.xml: <string name="latitude">Latitude: %1$d; Longitude: %2$d</string>

Answer (score -1):

```
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeTextview);
```

Cast the view to TextView and make sure you are using correct view id